# Data saved twice when it contains "select" word using CodeIgniter + PDO + SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, pdo

I have a CodeIgniter application and SQL Server database. I'm using PDO as a driver, everything works fine, but not when I'm trying to save data that contains the words "select" or "selection".

Example:

```
$data = array();
$data[] = array('title' => 'all you neeed', 'description' => 'description here');
$data[] = array('title' => 'try this selection', 'description' => 'description here');

$this->db->insert_batch($this->table, $data);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$data[]` contains ASSOC array instead of Numeric?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the probleme.

Comment: can you check $this->db->last_query();

Comment: INSERT INTO suggest(title, description) VALUES 
( 'all you neeed', 'description here'), 
( 'try this selection', 'description here')

Comment: @user2531572 Is there any error report? set `$config['log_threshold'] = 4` temporarily, do the action again and check the logs.

Comment: Already done, no errors or notice

Comment: May the CI community could help. it sounds like a bug.

Comment: I guess so...anyway, thx guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the pdo driver... I'm going to check github to see if this has been fixed or send a pull request to fix it. This issue has been fixed. I recommend updating your codeigniter install. I cloned the codeigniter repo @ github and was not able to replicate the error.

here is the bug: line 197 in pdo_driver.php

```
if (is_numeric(stripos($sql, 'SELECT')))
        {
            $this->affect_rows = count($result_id->fetchAll());
            $result_id->execute();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->affect_rows = $result_id->rowCount();
        }
```

here is the fix:

```
if (is_numeric(stripos($sql, 'SELECT')) && stripos($sql, 'SELECT') == 0)
        {
            $this->affect_rows = count($result_id->fetchAll());
            $result_id->execute();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->affect_rows = $result_id->rowCount();
        }
```